# Proving that $L$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ if and only if there exists a subsequence which converges to $L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I am not so sure if my proof is correct or not. I would really appreciate it if someone could check it for me. This is an exercise(paraphrased) from Analysis $1$ by Tao. I only want the proof of $(a) \implies (b)$ to be checked. I have already proven $(b) \implies (a)$.

Exercise: Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $L\in R$. Prove that $L$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ if and only if there exists a subsequence $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ that converges to $L$.

Proof: Suppose that $L$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$. We define the following numbers recursively. $$n_0 = 0 \\ n_j = \min \{n>n_{j-1} : |a_n - L|< \frac 1 j \}$$ Given that $L$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$, the above set is non-empty for every $j$. It's easy to show that $n_{j+1} > n_j$. Thus the sequence $(b_j)_{j=0}^\infty$, defined by $b_j = a_{n_j}$, is a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$.

Now let $\varepsilon > 0$. Note that $|b_j - L| < \frac 1 j$ and $|b_{j+1} - L|<\frac 1 {j+1} < \frac 1 j$. Thus, if we want to find an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we have that $|b_n - L| < \varepsilon$, we have to find a $j$ such that $\frac 1 j < \varepsilon$. Which happens if and only if $j > \frac 1 \varepsilon$. Thus, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, let $N > \frac 1 \varepsilon$. Then for all $n\ge N$, we have that $|b_n - L| < \varepsilon$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Isn’t $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ itself a subsequence? It’s been a while I did real analysis, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @user264745 It is indeed. But the hypothesis doesn’t assume that $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $L$

Comment: @Seeker Your proof looks correct to me.

Comment: I would probably add some justification that since $L$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ it is also a limit point of $(a_n)_{n>m}$, to justify the non-emptyness of the set you take the minimum of, unless you feel this is obvious enough

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @Carlyle I did originally write out the whole argument to prove the non-emptiness but felt that I could just reduce that to what I have in my post.